# Density function of product of mixed (distinct and continuous) indepedant random variables

Tags: probability

I have $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $P(Y = -2) = P(Y = 2) = \frac{1}{2}$.

How do i find density function $f_z(z)$ of $Z = X \cdot Y$?

Answer (score 1):

For instance, you can use Total Probability Law to find CDF first:
$$
F_Z(z)=\mathbb P(XY\leq z)=\mathbb P(XY\leq z, Y=-2)+\mathbb P(XY\leq z, Y=2)=$$
$$=\mathbb P(-2X\leq z, Y=-2)+\mathbb P(2X\leq z, Y=2)=\mathbb P(X\geq -z/2, Y=-2)+\mathbb P(X\leq z/2, Y=2).
$$
Then apply independence and symmetry of standard normal distribution. Or simply express both probabilities in terms of CDF of r.v. $X$. After that you can find derivative to get density function.